# Android Settings app - Default font sizes used for titles and subtitles

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-fonts

What font sizes are used by default in the Settings app for the titles and subtitles? The option in the red rectangle is an example.

[image]

Comment: There are dozens of Settings app implementations, spread across device manufacturers and various product lines/skins.

Comment: Are there any recommendations made by Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there even is a recommendation, I suppose it would be to use the default sizes used by the Jetpack Preferences library. These use

```
?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem
```

and

```
?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary
```

so it is pulling the text styles from the theme. In the latest Material Components theme, if you follow the chain of references all the way up to what font sizes they are using by default, they are `16sp` for the title and `14sp` for the summary.